# How could this question receive two reopen votes?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I've just found the linked question, [Equivalent for "Crowd" in the context of machines](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355442/equivalent-for-crowd-in-the-context-of-machines), received two reopen votes.

I checked the review history and three users voted to keep this question left closed. (This question is not about how the reopen queue works. I am just stating the fact.)

The question title reads like it is looking for a synonym of *crowd*, but the question body reads very clearly that it is looking for a word or phrase that could refer to *process of outsourcing a task to a set of machines*. All the answers are suggesting synonyms of *crowd* or *to source*.

The bigger issue I see is the OP has not responded to the request to make it clearer.

Can we pay a little more attention when we vote to reopen an unclear question or Single Word Requests (SWR)?

Comment: Did you really just create the *vote-to-reopen* tag for this question?

Comment: @Helmar Yes, I did. Anything wrong?

Comment: Users should be allowed to judge for themselves whether the question is useful and shows research/is clear or unclear/meets certain standards. There will always be users who feel differently about things than you do. And sometimes some people believe they understand questions/requests that others find confusing. E.g., I never answer IT questions because I don't know the first thing about it. But for the same reason, I seldom vote to close them.

Comment: @medica That smells almost like an upvotable answer. :)

Comment: I am often amazed at the questions that get reopened, after being closed for quite valid reasons.  Usually there have been trivial edits to the question which are claimed to have "fixed" it, but the "fixes" are hardly ever effective.  (In the above question I don't even see any edits.)

Comment: @medica Your logic doesn't work. Your comment sounds like I should not answer/close-vote/reopen-vote IT questions because I don't know the first thing about it. Even if I don't know the first thing about IT, I know the question is unclear because it is written in English, not **Itish**. Do you really think the question is about IT?

Comment: @HotLicks In the above question, the reopen vote was triggered by a user who simply voted to reopen it. I doubt the voter had read the question.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree. OP cited crowdsourcing to convey the idea of a "set of machines", probably not a good example, but, at least to me, it is clear they are looking for a synonym for "crowd"  that may apply to "machines". " ***So, what is the equivalent term for the collection of (artificially or physically) machines?***.  Those who answered referring to crowdsourcing probably didn't read carefully. The question could be improved, though.

Comment: @JOSH You seem to have misunderstood what "crowdsourcing" means in business context. It doesn't mean the equivalent of "set of machines". It is used to source (obtain) some funds, labor, contents from outside the company. It's not a difficult term to understand. If users think the question could be improved, they have to wait until the OP edits the question before blindly voting to reopen it. The question is asking basically two (or three) completely different questions and the answers posted prove the question is unclear. Also you need to note that SWR question must have an example.

Comment: @Rathony - I know what it means and as I said  it is a poor example, but the question is clear in asking what is the "crowd" equivalent term for a "set of machines".  I tent to see the "good part of questions", not only the "bad" one.

Comment: @JOSH "Specifically, how one could refer to **process of outsourcing a task to a set of machines**?" Does any of the answers answer this question? **Specifically** means the OP is narrowing down the question to a specific word or phrase. It is not seeking the equivalent of "set of machines". Can you read the question again?

Comment: My last comment,  the question is: ***So, what is the equivalent term for the collection of (artificially or physically) machines?*** - ***Specifically,*** (how one could refer to process of outsourcing a task to)  ***a set of machines?***

Comment: @JOSH I don't understand your logic. (It's my last comment, too) Don't you think "**Specifically, how one could refer to a set of machines to which process of outsourcing a task is applied?**" would be a better question than the one asked in the OP? What I mean is there should be an example sentence where the word would be used. Don't forget we have a close reason, **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. The linked question proves that we have to stick to this rule. We should wait 'til the question is *edited*.

Comment: @Rathony - More than one user voted to reopen.

Comment: @Rathony I just wonder which kind of questions are to be addressed with that tag. It seems to me that the closed-questions covers this already. The questions with that tag are: "Can/Should X be reopened?" and "Why was X reopened?" This question is in the latter category. Personally, I don't see the merit of the additional tag.

Answer (score 2):

A completed review in the reöpen queue does nothing to remove current reöpen votes if there are any, nor to prevent new ones from appearing.

Those reöpen votes must therefore exist because two members voted to reöpen that question. The reöpen review queue will be unrelated to those votes.

Comment: I don't think your post answers my question. I am asking how the question could receive two reopen votes, not how to remove current reopen votes nor how the reopen queue works.

Comment: _ __ __ __ _ Reöpen?

Comment: @Rathony In that case there is no answerable question here, merely a rant. No one but the anonymous voters themselves  can explain why they did as they did.

Comment: @tchrist Well, I am asking other users to be more careful. If you consider it as rant, I don't have anything to say.

Comment: @Helmar I’m imagining your Teutonic orthographic sensibilities might could stand some reällignment from reading diæ̈reses as umlautings. :)

Comment: +1. Can’t we all just coöperate?

Comment: @tchrist But why diæ̈reses?